# Почему вася?

Tags: этимология

Недавно объясняла,что значит слово "аффилированный" и сказала так: ну, они между собой "вась-вась"

Вот и подумала: почему именно Вася является образцом близких отношений? Да еще с сомнительным оттенком.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*[Вась-вась](http://enc-dic.com/russaying/Vas-vas-39.html)*, судя по всему пришло к нам с воровского жаргона. Конкретно этимологию этого выражения найти нигде не удалось, но [*Васьком*](http://enc-dic.com/thief/Vasek-628.html) на этом жаргоне называют ещё и товарища. Если так, то получается *вась-вась* - это, он меня товарищем считает и я его тоже.

Comment: Очень похоже!

Answer (score 5):

Вась-вась - конечно, фамильярное от имени Василий.Если рассматривать имя Василий в контексте творчества Зощенко, то имя это воспринимается негативно:    
http://litg.ru/journ/vasyazoschenko.  Произведения, в которых совершается кража или другие подобные действия, если в них герой имеет имя, то герой будет назван Васей. Это такое универсальное установление личности и ее типа. В том произведении, где фигурирует Васька, Василий, Вася, герой даже может иметь данное автором отчество, но все равно – перед вами характерный тип жулика, вора, мошенника, в общем, не очень чистого на руку гражданина.Получается, что "мы с ним "вась-вась"..."- когда  нас связывает  что-то общее, тайное, мы как бы подельники.

Comment: У меня именно такое восприятие! Хотя в словарях вроде нет "жуликоватого" оттенка.

Comment: Во времена Зощенко имя Василий было одним из самых распространённых. Если брать XIX век, то по по популярности имя уступало только Ивану. [Статья на эту тему.](http://medconfer.com/node/2219) Однако после революции наметилась тенденция к уменьшению Василиев, особенно среди горожан. Т.е. это имя судя по всему воспринималось, как нечто старорежимное и деревенское, но ещё проявляющиеся и в городе. Так что в использовании этого имени Зощенко нет ничего удивительного.

Answer (score 2):

В древнерусском языке склонение личного местоимения второго лица множественного числа "вы" будет "вась".

Comment: Простите, а это в каком падеже? )))))

Answer (score -1):

Выражение "вась-вась" пришло из арабского языка (وسوس "васваса" - нашёптывать, внушать злые мысли). Когда я стала изучать арабский язык, то заметила, что в нашем языке есть много слов, имеющих арабское происхождение, о происхождении которых мы и не догадывались. И никакого отношения к Васям это слово не имеет))). [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пусть трижды к Васям и Василисам не имеет отношения, но к злому и к тревожному-то — с какой стати?